# How can I write in (GNU) C a proxy function to interface two different calling conventions?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I'm writing an interpreter/compiler hybrid where the calling convention passes parameters on the CPU stack. Functions are simply pointers to machine code (like C function pointers) potentially generated at runtime. I need a proxy function to interface with the custom calling convention. **I want to write as much as possible of this function in C**, although necessarily some parts will have to be written in assembly. I will refer to this proxy function as `apply`.

I don't fully understand the semantics of GCC inline assembly and **I would like to know if the following *tentative*** implementation of a 1-ary `apply` function **is correct, or where it goes wrong**. In particular, I wonder about the integrity of the stack between the many `__asm__` blocks: how does the compiler (GCC and clang in my case) interpret the stack pointer register being clobbered, and what are the consequences of that in the generated code? Does the compiler understand that I want to "own" the stack? Is the `memory` clobber necessary?

Through experimentation I found that clang with `-fomit-frame-pointer` correctly disables this optimization for a function when it sees the `rsp` register in a clobber list, since `rsp` is obviously not anymore a reliable way of addressing local variables on the stack. This is not true in GCC, and as a consequence it generates buggy code (this seems like a bug in GCC). So I guess this answers some of my questions. I can live with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, but it seems as if GCC doesn't consider the various implications of `rsp` being clobbered.

This is written for x86-64, although I am interested in eventually porting it to other architectures. We assume all registers are preserved across calls in the custom calling convention.

```c
#define push(x) \
    __asm__ volatile ("pushq %0;" : : "g" (x) : "rsp", "memory")

#define pop(n) \
    __asm__ volatile ("addq %0, %%rsp;" : : "g" (n * 8) : "rsp", "memory")

#define call(f) \
    __asm__ volatile ("callq *%0;" : : "g" (f) : "cc", "memory")

void apply(void* f, void* x) {
  push(x);
  call(f);
  pop(1);
}
```

I think the `-mno-red-zone` flag is technically necessary to use the stack in the way I want. Is this correct?

---

The previous code assumes all registers are preserved across calls. But if there's a set of registers which *aren't* preserved, how should I reflect this in the code? I get the feeling that adding them to the `call` clobber list won't produce correct results because the registers may be pushed onto the top of the stack, shadowing the pushed `x`. If instead they are saved on a previously reserved area of the call frame, it may work. Is this the case? Can I rely on this behaviour? (Is it silly of me to hope so?)

Another option would be to manually preserve and restore these registers but I have a strong feeling this will only give the *illusion* of safety and break at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a proxy function to interface with the custom calling convention. **I want to write as much as possible of this function in C**, although necessarily some parts will have to be written in assembly.

I'm sorry, this simply will not work.  You must write the entire proxy function in assembly language.

More concretely -- I don't know about clang, but GCC assumes at a very basic level that nobody touches the stack pointer in inline assembly, ever.  That doesn't mean it will error out -- it means it will blithely mis-optimize on the assumption that you didn't do that, *even though you told it you did*.  This is not something that is likely ever to change; it's baked into the register allocator and all umpteen CPU back ends.

Now, the good news is, you *may* be able to persuade [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) to do what you want.  It's got proxy functions which someone else has written in assembly language for you; if it fits your use case, it'll save you quite a bit of trouble.

Comment: Well, it's good to have a definitive answer. I have looked into libffi but it lacks support for variadic functions, which I need. I guess I'll have to roll my own. Thank you.

Comment: What if you had a single inline assembly block, that undid its changes to the stack pointer before it finished?

Comment: @immibis That will work as long as you don't need to be able to throw exceptions out of, or through, that block.  The more basic problems start when you change the distance between the stack pointer and the top of the current call frame -- the compiler needs to know the exact value of that distance at the beginning of every instruction it emits, but an assembly insert is treated as a single monolithic "instruction", so changes in the middle don't cause problems (except, as I mentioned, that the unwind tables will not be correct).

Comment: Well I thought that was what @zwol meant by saying to write the entire function in assembly language. I'd think there'd be no issue in modifying the stack pointer in an inline assembly block as long as it's restored to its original state at exit. But the `-mno-red-zone` flag would be needed.

Comment: Since I'm not dealing with C++ here I believe unwinding wouldn't be an issue for me, am I right?

Comment: @frangio I personally would recommend writing a `.s` file rather than a C function whose entire body was a single assembly insert, to ensure you know exactly what the prologue and epilogue are doing.  But the latter _can_ be made to work.  Unwinding is a concern if any of the _called_ code can, directly or indirectly, throw exceptions - your code might not itself be C++, but does it call anything that is?  Another reason to write an `.s` file is, then you can use `.cfi_*` directives safely.